# AWS Device Farm- Testing Stuck at Login Page

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am running AWS Device Farm to test my iOS App. I am using Built-in: Fuzz Test Framework.

AWS test is stuck at Login Page(obviously). Is there a way to bypass the Login Page so that testing can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately AWS Device Farm Fuzz runs do not provide a way to bypass Login Pages.

If you where testing an Android App they do provide Explorer tests that come with that feature.